# Non-greedy configurations across steps

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using late acceptance as local search algorithm and here is how it actually picks moves:

1. If my forager is 5, it'll pick 5 moves and then get 1 random move to be applied for every step.
2. At every step it only picks moves that are increasing scores ie greedy picking across steps.

Forager.pickMove()

```
public LocalSearchMoveScope pickMove(LocalSearchStepScope stepScope) {
        stepScope.setSelectedMoveCount(selectedMoveCount);
        stepScope.setAcceptedMoveCount(acceptedMoveCount);
        if (earlyPickedMoveScope != null) {
            return earlyPickedMoveScope;
        }
        List<LocalSearchMoveScope> finalistList = finalistPodium.getFinalistList();
        if (finalistList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (finalistList.size() == 1 || !breakTieRandomly) {
            return finalistList.get(0);
        }
        int randomIndex = stepScope.getWorkingRandom().nextInt(finalistList.size());// should have checked for best here
        return finalistList.get(randomIndex);
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. In first, can we make forager to pick the best of 5 instead of pick 1 randomly.
2. Can we allow move to pick that degrades score but can increase score later(no way to know it)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for `acceptedCountLimit` and `selectedCountLimit` in the docs. Those do exactly that.
2. That's already the case (especially with Late Acceptance and Simulated Annealing). In the DEBUG log, just look at the step score vs the best score. Or ask for the step score statistic in optaplanner-benchmark.